# Как передать изменение значения в глобальную переменную(result)

Tags: javascript

Моей задачей было: вывести ссылку на значение, которое находиться в массиве. По типу:`findPath(obj) === "subobj.arr.1.x"`
С простыми значениями легко, но вот значение, которое находиться в объекте, в котором есть массив, другое дело. В codsandbox код работает без ошибок, но в node выкидывает ошибку, потому что result = undefined вне замыкания. Прошу помочь решить эту проблему: как можно перезаписать result, что бы логика кода не нарушалась или альтернативу моему коду, которое будет работать без подобных ошибок, и выполнять поставленную задачу. Вот условие задачи: Напишите функцию, принимающую к качестве аргумента объект с данными, и возвращающую путь, по которому в этом объекте находится поле со значением 15. В объекте всегда не больше одного значения 15.

```js
function findPath(obj) {
  var result;
  
  function iter(o, p) {
    return Object.keys(o).some(function(k) {
      result = p.concat(Array.isArray(o) ? +k : k);
      console.log(result);
      return o[k] === 15 || (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' && iter(o[k], result));
    });
  }
  
  console.log(result);
  return (iter(obj, []) && result).join('.') || null;
}

console.log(findPath({
  field1: "hello, world",
  name: "Johnny",
  t: 99,
  almostthere: "15",
  subobj: {
    name: 13,
    arr: [
      { g: -4, k: 1 },
      { test: NaN, x: 15 },
    ],
  },
  test: "g",
}));
```

Comment: А какое именно значение ты хочешь достать из этой структуры вложенных объектов? То есть, почему именно путь к свойству `x` возвращается, а не к `g` например, откуда взялось это условие на `15` хардкодом? Очень непонятно все :) задачку бы пояснить...

Comment: Вот условие: Напишите функцию, принимающую к качестве аргумента объект с данными, и возвращающую путь, по которому в этом объекте находится поле со значением 15. В объекте всегда не больше одного значения 15.

Comment: Попробовал в ноде выполнить код из вoпроса - ошибок не получил. Чисто визуально тоже все в порядке, так что хз... Вариант чуть пооптимальнее запостил ответом (правда, не нравится мне что индексы элементов вложенных массивов в результате тоже через точку, а не в квадратных скобочках, но раз надо альтернативу с тем же результатом выполнения, то так даже проще).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function findPath(object, searchValue) {
  let isFound = false;
  const path = [];
  const findProp = obj => Object.entries(obj).some(([key, val]) => {
    isFound = isFound || (val === searchValue)         // если искомое еще не найдено - сравним со значением текущего свойства...
      || ((typeof val === 'object') && findProp(val)); // ...а при неудаче сравнения и объектном типе тек. значения, выполним рекурсивный вызов
    if (isFound) path.push(key);                       // когда искомое найдено, запоминаем фрагменты пути "на обратном пути" из рекурсивных вызовов
    return isFound;
  });
  return !findProp(object) ? null : path.reverse().join('.');
}

const testObj = {
  field1: "hello, world",
  name: "Johnny",
  t: 99,
  almostthere: "15",
  subobj: {
    name: 13,
    arr: [
      { g: -4, k: 1 },
      { test: NaN, x: 15 },
    ],
  },
  test: "g",
};
console.log(findPath(testObj, 15));
```